# Prove the sum is a Lipschitz function

Tags: real-analysis

> Show that the series $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{k+|x|}$$ converges for each $x\in R$ and the sum is a Lipschitz function.

By alternating series test, this is a convergent series.

Then how to prove this sum is a Lipschitz function? The definition of Lipschitz function is $|f(x)-f(y)|\le M|x-y|$, which is $\sum_{k=1}^\infty [\frac{(-1)^k}{k+|x|}-\frac{(-1)^k}{k+|y|}]\le M|x-y|$. Then I don't know how to proceed.

Could anyone kindly help about this? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$|{1 \over k+|x|} - {1 \over k+|y|}| = |{|y|-|x| \over (k+|x|)(k+|y|)}| \le {1 \over k^2}||y|-|x|| \le {1 \over k^2}|y-x| $, and ${1 \over k^2}$ is summable.